# Dropdown and react-i18next

Tags: react-i18next

I have a dropdown with a list of countries that it has been translated well, as I want. Even that I can navigate down and up from the dropdown I can't select any option. Any explanation, help, or solution to this issue?

```
`const _createMenuItems = menuItems =>
  menuItems.map((item, index) => (
    <I18n>
   {t =>{ 
  return( 
    <MenuItem key={index} value={item} primaryText={t(item)} />
     )
  }}  
</I18n>
  )
  )`
```